# How to map a sequence to a transition matrix

Tags: time-series, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, transition-matrix

I have the following transition matrices, one for `Maria` and one for `Anna`:

```
import pandas as pd
anna_dt = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['tomato', 'carrots', 'cheese'],
                              'tomato': [0.1, 0.4, 0.1],
                              'carrots': [0.5,0.5,0.1],
                               'cheese': [0.4,0.1,0.8]})
maria_dt = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['tomato', 'carrots', 'cheese'],
                              'tomato': [0.7, 0.4, 0.8],
                              'carrots': [0.15,0.3,0.1],
                               'cheese': [0.15,0.3,0.1]})

anna_dt
source  tomato  carrots cheese
0   tomato  0.1 0.5 0.4
1   carrots 0.4 0.5 0.1
2   cheese  0.1 0.1 0.8

maria_dt
source  tomato  carrots cheese
0   tomato  0.7 0.15    0.15
1   carrots 0.4 0.30    0.30
2   cheese  0.8 0.10    0.10
```

What these matrices tell me, is that e.g., there is an `80%` chance that `Anna` is eating `cheese` after eating `cheese` and `40%` that `Anna` is eating `tomato` after eating `carrots`

Similarly for `Maria` we have that she has `70%` chance that she is `tomato` after eating `tomato` and `80%` chance that she is `tomato` after eating `cheese`.

My question is:

- Given a sequence of foods: `carrots -> carrots -> tomato -> carrots -> tomato -> cheese -> cheese -> cheese`, how can I calculate the probability of this sequence belonging to `Anna` and the probability of this sequence belonging to `Maria` ? (this sequence is most like belonging to `Anna` since we can see a lot of `carrots` followed by `carrots` and a lot of `cheese` followed by `cheese`)

Comment: Interesting question.  Have you thought of computing and comparing the two likelihoods for the observed sequence?

Comment: @whuber I guess this would be one way. I did calculate the likelihood for `Anna` and `Maria` and for `Anna` was 0.01 and for `Maria` was 0.00001, so this should do.

I guess another way (conceptually similar) would be to simulate 10k, 8-step chains for each matrix and and see for which matrix the requested sequence pops up more often

Comment: Computing the likelihoods will be *much* faster and more accurate ;-).  The simulation ought to produce equivalent results if it's large enough.